# Homebrew is generating two warnings

Tags: macos, homebrew, package-managers

I use Homebrew as the package manager.   I run this command:

```
brew update
```

But I  got this error:

> error: unable to unlink old 'bin/brew' (Permission denied)
>
> Error: Failed while executing git pull http://github.com/mxcl/homebrew.git master

Running again under sudo:

> /usr/local/Library/Homebrew/brew.h.rb:1: warning: already initialized constant FORMULA_META_FILES
>   /usr/local/Library/Homebrew/brew.h.rb:2: warning: already initialized constant PLEASE_REPORT_BUG
>   error: The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by checkout:
>
> .gitignore
>   ;;; big list goes here ;;;;

And now, every brew command generates these warning:

> /usr/local/Library/Homebrew/brew.h.rb:1: warning: already initialized constant FORMULA_META_FILES
>   /usr/local/Library/Homebrew/brew.h.rb:2: warning: already initialized constant PLEASE_REPORT_BUG

Any idea what is going wrong?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

It sounds like half of it updated before it errored out, and now it's in a bad state. You may want to

```
cd /usr/local && git reset --hard HEAD
```

That should reset all git-controlled files (e.g. homebrew) back to their pristine versions. You may need to `sudo` that git command. After that, you can attempt to fix the permissions however you want (this may be as simple as running `sudo chown -R yourname:staff /usr/local` if no files in that dir need to be owned by someone else).

Comment: So, it is Git issue and not brew? Sorry, I'm not familiar with Git.

Comment: It's not a git issue. It's a permissions issue encountered while using git to update the brew install.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that /usr/local/bin has write permissions for the user account.

Comment: Worked for me, "bin/" had an unknown UID number :)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue today, this pointed me in the right direction, but the reset was not enough. I am not sure how, but somehow I had quite a few untracked files, I noticed after running **git status**.

I finally made a copy of all the files (just to be safe) and deleted them, after that brew update worked like a charm